# Lua case sensitive and whole word search

Tags: lua

Could anyone tell me how to toggle case sensitive searching on string find?

Also whole word searching?, is this even possible?, I figured I could concat a space character to the beginning and end of the string I want to look for but this wont work if the searched word is at the start or end of the string.

Comment: any group of letters and/or numbers that have no spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me how to toggle case sensitive searching on string find?

There is no case-insensitive flag/toggle in Lua's pattern-api. See:

- http://www.lua.org/pil/20.4.html
- [Case-insensitive Lua pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401890/case-insensitive-lua-pattern-matching)

> Also whole word searching?, is this even possible?,

Lua's pattern matching has no "word boundary" meta-char, like other pattern-match/regex api's have. So the answer is: "no".

> I figured I could concat a space character to the beginning and end of the string I want to look for but this wont work if the searched word is at the start or end of the string.

It's a bit trickier than that: think about punctuation marks.

Comment: @Mick: Actually, lua 5.2 patterns have a "%f" modifier that should be able to emulate word boundaries. This is not included in the 5.1 specificaion but I head that they still work as an undocumented extension there.