# Finding a string lua

Tags: lua

How to implement search for a part of a string without letter case

```
a = {["hello"] = 1,["Hello"] = 2}

for i in pairs(a) do
if string.find(i, "h") then print(i)
```

--should be "hello" and "Hello"

Answer (score 3):

Use [pattern character sets](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1), and include both cases.

```lua
local a = {
    ["hello"] = 1,
    ["Hello"] = 2
}

for i in pairs(a) do
    if string.find(i, "[hH]") then
        print(i)
    end
end
```

For something more robust, see [Case-insensitive Lua pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11401890).